# Netezza vs Puredata

Tags: netezza

That this question may seem awkward but I searched for a whole week to know the difference of Netezza and PureData. I appreciate anyone could help me.
If you could provide me a link would be much better.

Comment: "puredata"  (aka Pd) is a real-time graphical programming environment for audio, video, and graphical processing. please do not use this tag for questions related to IBM's PureData systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PureData is a family of IBM products. In the family, there are:

IBM PureData for Analytics - Formerly known as Netezza. It is based on Netezza and is aimed for business intelligence and data warehousing (OLAP) applications.

IBM PureData for Operational Analytics - Formerly known as IBM Smart Analytics System. It is based on DB2 DPF and is aimed for real-time decision making and data warehousing (OLAP) applications.

IBM PureData for Transactions - It is based on DB2 PureScale and is aimed for transactional (OLTP) applications.

IBM PureData for Hadoop - It is based on InfoSphere BigInsights and is aimed for Big Data applications.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that Netezza and PureData System for Analytics (aka PDA) are the same thing.

The longer answer is that Netezza (a company) produced a data warehouse appliance (also commonly referred to as Netezza).  [IBM acquired Netezza in 2010](https://www-03.ibm.com/press/us/en/pressrelease/32955.wss), and subsequently re-branded the appliance as the PureData System for Analytics. Within IBM the PureData family of systems is an umbrella for their appliances and what they refer to as Expert Integrated Systems.

The software that runs on today's PDA systems is still known as Netezza Performance Server (aka NPS).

[This link](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/netezza/) is somewhat dated, but explains the rebranding simply, and also provides [this link to the current product page](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/puredata/analytics/index.html).

Comment: So it means that PureData System for Analytics is a sub product under IBM PureData main product which before acquisition it was known by Netezza. And this is why they always bring Powered by Netezza after PureData System for Analytics.